# Discrepancy between Fourier Coefficents Formula (a_0)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've been reading up on the Fourier Series and have come across formulae for the coefficients. In my notes, I have the following formula

$$a_n=1/\pi\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)cos(nx)dx$$
for n=0,1,2,3,4...

From this I can derive a_0, (cos(0x)=1),
$$a_0=1/\pi\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)dx$$

However, in most other places, a direct a_0 formula is given like this,
$$a_0=1/2\pi\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)dx$$

My question is how come in some places it's 1/2pi and in other places they don't provide a formula for it and you can derive it using the a_n formula which ends up to give you 1/pi

Comment: In those book, the series would have been written as, $f(x) = a_0+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (b_n\sin(nx)+a_n\cos(nx))$, instead of  $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (b_n\sin(nx)+a_n\cos(nx))$

Comment: Ah. Yes, it is written like that. Perfect. Thank you!